# How to create classes in specs without polluting global namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

What's the best way to define a class within the context of a spec, and not have it pollute the global namespace? How does the other file even get access to that constant?

bowling_spec.rb

```rb
require "spec_helper"

describe Bowling do
  context "when validate is defined" do
    let(:dummy_class) {
      Class.new(described_class) do
        METRICS_NAMESPACE = "ExtendedClass.Metrics.namespace"
      end
    }

    it "does nothing" do
      dummy_class 
    end
  end
end
```

Spec - batting_spec.rb

```rb
require "spec_helper"

describe Batting do
  context do
    it "does weird thing" do
      expect { self.class.const_get(:METRICS_NAMESPACE) }.to raise_error(NameError)
    end
  end
end
```

If you run the individual spec file

```
rspec spec/batting_spec.rb
.

Finished in 0.00285 seconds (files took 0.12198 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

If you run the spec which defines the dummy class

```
rspec spec/bowling_spec.rb spec/batting_spec.rb
.F

Failures:

  1) Batting  does weird thing
     Failure/Error: expect { self.class.const_get(:METRICS_NAMESPACE) }.to raise_error(NameError)
       expected NameError but nothing was raised
     # ./spec/batting_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.01445 seconds (files took 0.12715 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/batting_spec.rb:5 # Batting  does weird thing
```

To reproduce the error: I created a repo: https://github.com/pratik60/rspec-pollution with updated Readme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running  `rspec spec/batting_spec.rb spec/bowling_spec.rb`

`2 examples, 0 failures`

Running `rspec spec/bowling_spec.rb spec/batting_spec.rb`
Gives the error you mention.

Using binding.pry:

```
describe Batting do
  context do
    it "does weird thing" do
      require 'pry'
      binding.pry
      expect { self.class.const_get(:METRICS_NAMESPACE) }.to raise_error(NameError)
    end
  end
end
```

**self.class.ancestors**

```
[RSpec::ExampleGroups::Batting::Anonymous,
 RSpec::ExampleGroups::Batting::Anonymous::LetDefinitions,
 RSpec::ExampleGroups::Batting::Anonymous::NamedSubjectPreventSuper,
 RSpec::ExampleGroups::Batting,
 RSpec::ExampleGroups::Batting::LetDefinitions,
 RSpec::ExampleGroups::Batting::NamedSubjectPreventSuper,
 RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup,
```

**Going down the inheritance tree**

```
RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::METRICS_NAMESPACE
(pry):4: warning: toplevel constant METRICS_NAMESPACE referenced by RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::METRICS_NAMESPACE
=> "ExtendedClass.Metrics.namespace"
```

**Checking the first object on the chain**

`Object::METRICS_NAMESPACE`

```
=>"ExtendedClass.Metrics.namespace"
```

**Even further**

```
Class::METRICS_NAMESPACE
(pry):2: warning: toplevel constant METRICS_NAMESPACE referenced by Class::METRICS_NAMESPACE
=> "ExtendedClass.Metrics.namespace"
```

**TL ; DR**

As you said, when you did `METRICS_NAMESPACE = "ExtendedClass.Metrics.namespace"`, you created a global namespace constant. (That is, a constant inside the uppermost ruby constant, Class)

Simply do this instead

```
Class.new(described_class) do
        self.const_set('METRICS_NAMESPACE', "ExtendedClass.Metrics.namespace")
      end
```

**rspec spec/bowling_spec.rb spec/batting_spec.rb**

```
Finished in 1.55 seconds (files took 0.08012 seconds to load)
2 examples, 0 failures
```